# Not able to login with Skype Web SDK Online Sample

Tags: office365, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype4java

I have downloaded Skype Web SDK sample and hosted locally.

I am using **SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample**. When I am entering my office 365 credentials. it will redirect the UI page. And appear the loading screen.

[image]

Network and Console error trace is as under 
[image]

It will show the user Unauthorized. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Skype for business online requires the user to login with the Azure AD login page, which will check your user credentials and then return to your web app with an authentication token. This should automatically happen after you receive the 401, is the Azure AD login screen shown?

Comment: I have hosted locally and running successfully. But I am not able to join the meeting anonymously. (Even UI does not appear). Check it out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303327/how-to-enable-the-join-meeting-option)