# How to enable the Join Meeting Option?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype4java

I am using **SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample**. I have hosted locally and running successfully.

Some of functionalities are not running

1. Self (Error: NoResourceFound)
2. Conference (UI appeared But Functionality not working)
3. Join Meeting (Even UI does not appear)

[image]

Although,I have given all delegated rights for Skype for Business Online.
When I am decoding the token, It will give me only 2 scopes in scp key.

[image]
[image]

Is it need to follow the prerequisites steps for it?
(http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/04/learn-skype-web-api-day-2-server-prerequisites/)

When I am creating anonymous meeting,It will throw the error.
Source code:

```
var uri = 'sip:kunjal.bhatt@example.com;gruu;opaque-app:conf:focus:id:1WRB13D2';
window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.signIn({
  name: 'Robin',
  meeting: uri
});
```

Error:

```
CommandDisabled
    at Object.Exception (https://latest-swx.cdn.skype.com/v/1.72.36/js/skype-web-sdk.js:18961:31)
    at BaseModel.pm_command [as signIn] (https://latest-swx.cdn.skype.com/v/1.72.36/js/skype-web-sdk.js:20147:37)
    at <anonymous>:1:34
```

How to enable the Join Meeting Option?

Comment: You would not have access to the server to make any changes.  You may want to look at the samples located at [ucwa.skype.com](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk) and see if you are able to login using Azure AD and test out the samples.

Comment: when I am creating the Anonymous meeting it will throw the error.(I have added in above question)

Comment: I do not believe Skype for Business Online has anonymous meeting join enabled.  I believe it would be a new delegated permission as the Initiate Meetings and Join Conversations permissions is specific to the user account.